# strange snmp response

Tags: snmp

I'm new to SNMP.

Installed an SNMP server (net-snmp 5.4.3 on Debian), and I`m trying to go through this tutorial : http://oreilly.com/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/twenty-minute-snmp-tutorial.html

I am getting a strange response for the following query:

```
# snmpgetnext -v 1 -c public localhost  \
    ip.ipRouteTable.ipRouteEntry.ipRouteDest \
    ip.ipRouteTable.ipRouteEntry.ipRouteNextHop

HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (67626825) 7 days, 19:51:08.25
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (67626825) 7 days, 19:51:08.25
```

I would expect to get some routing table information, but instead I get the system uptime (twice).

any idea why?

Comment: Can you try doing `snmpwalk -v 1 -c public localhost | grep ipRouteDest`?  I think it may be because snmpd is not actually giving you all of the OIDs due to permissions on the public community.

Comment: returns nothing. I did have a permission issue, new error message for the query above is two lines like:Unknown Object Identifier (Sub-id not found: (top) -> ip)

Comment: Do any of the tutorial examples work on your target device? Is snmp running?

Comment: My guess is that you have one or more screwed mibs (where the text is translated to its actual value). In particular you may want to check the values in the host-resources mib.